# How can I switch from forward to backward search in Vim?

Tags: vim

In Vim, I know that `/` will search forward from the cursor, with `n` and `N` repeating the search forward and backward, respectively.

I also know that `?` will search backward from the cursor, with `n` and `N` repeating the search backward and forward, respectively.

My question is, if I've done a `?` search, and I want to re-run that as a `/` search (so I don't have to keep holding shift to move forward), is there a way to switch the previous search's direction without retyping the search term?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Simply typing a `?` without any text following it will re-run the search backwards.

I.e. typing `/` <kbd>Return</kbd> or `?` <kbd>Return</kbd> will always rerun the last search, but in the direction you want.

Comment: Wow, that was way easier than I thought. :) Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, and apparently, ? or / followed by the up key cycles through a common history for the two. I thought each had their own history.

Comment: Just a minor thing (looks pretty obvious), but I did miss it. You have to navigate to end of the file (ctrl + end) to reverse search it.

Answer (score 2):

Is this more easier?

> ctrl-o, ctrl-i - go through jump locations

[Searching REF](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/help/vim/searching.html)